# ¿Error con JOIN?

Tags: mysql

Buen día, trataré de explicarme. Tengo las siguientes tablas, 'entradas' y 'categorias':

[image: tablas]

Lo que estoy buscando es obtener una consulta en la que me arroje como resultado las categorías y, a un lado, el numero de ocasiones que se ha usado esa categoría en la tabla 'entradas'.

Esto ya lo he logrado con la función INNER JOIN, así:

```
SELECT categorias.nombre, COUNT(*) 
FROM entradas 
INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias.id = entradas.id_categorias 
GROUP BY id_categorias;
```

El resultado es este:

[image: innerjoin]

Ahora lo que intento es hacer lo mismo, pero que el resultado también me arroje la categoría que aun no se ha usado, en este caso 'Plataformas', y junto, me marque un 0 o NULL, algo que me indique que es una categoría aun sin usar. Para esto tengo entendido que me servirían las funciones LEFT JOIN o RIGHT JOIN, y lo he hecho así:

```
SELECT categorias.nombre, COUNT(*) 
FROM entradas 
RIGHT JOIN categorias ON entradas.id_categorias = categorias.id 
GROUP BY id_categorias;
```

Pero me arroja esto:

[image: select]

En la categoría 'Plataformas' me marca 1, cuando debería aparecer 0. Intenté probar a quitar el GROUP BY, y me arroja esto:

[image: prueba]

Aparece una suma de 11, cuando en mi tabla entradas hay solo 10 registros. Parece como si existiera un registro en la tabla 'entradas' con el id_categorias=5 pero en realidad no es así. No entiendo que es lo que puede estar pasando.

Comment: Ya llevas tiempo en el sitio, tienes varias preguntas y respuestas ... ya deberías saber que **las imágenes** no están bien vistas aquí, hace difícil para los demás el poder ayudarte. Por favor, sustituyelas por **texto**.

Comment: Ya he probado con el LEFT JOIN y me sale el mismo resultado.

Comment: Puse las imágenes porque pensé seria la forma mas sencilla de comprender mi problema. Pero si no esta bien hecho las quito. ¿Como hago para poner esas mismas imágenes en texto, las pongo como un simple texto normal?

Comment: Oscar puedes copiar y pegar cada texto en la pregunta y luego seleccionas todo el bloque y presionas **`{  }`**  así queda identado y mucho más útil que las imágenes para casos como este.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que tu consulta debería ser reacomodada de este modo, para poder trabajar con `LEFT JOIN` para que obtengas todas las categorias que si tienen una o mas entradas asociadas y además aquellas categorías que no tienen ninguna asociada

```
SELECT categorias.nombre, COUNT(entradas.id_categorias) 
FROM categorias 
LEFT JOIN entradas ON categorias.id = entradas.id_categorias 
GROUP BY id_categorias;
```

**ACLARACIONES**

- Selecciono primero el nombre de la categoría al ser la tabla del lado izquierdo en mi representación
- Hago el `count()` pero de la columna `id_categorias` puesto que es la llave foránea que vincula ambas tablas y es la que indica si el nombre de una categoría ha sido o no registrado
- En el `FROM` coloco que sea desde categoría
- Hago un `LEFT JOIN` para mostrar los datos de ambas tablas que esten vinculados y además me muestre los datos de la tabla izquierda `categorias` que aún no han sido utilizados, es decir el nombre de la categoria en la tabla de la derecha `entradas`
- En el `ON` igualo en que columnas se hace la vinculación entre ambas tablas
- Finalmente se queda el `GROUP BY()` del `id_categorias`

Aqui tienes un [enlace](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=03f310082158ab149a8c47e74e953abb) donde puedes corroborar lo que te menciono

**RESULTADO DE LA CONSULTA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Básicamente mi error estaba en el `count()`. Modificandolo es que se resuelve mi problema.